# Why does function(){} not work, but (function(){}) does? (Chrome DevTools/Node)

Tags: javascript

I've seen this odd behavior right now that I could not define

```
function(){}
```

or

```
function(a){
   console.log(a)
}
```

It throws an `Uncaught SyntaxError`.

But `test = function(){}` or `(function(){})` did work.

The Safari dev tools have a better error report: It says

> SyntaxError: Function statements must have a name.

Okay it makes no sense to define a function like that if you will never use it. But it's still odd. I guess I have already provided the answer in the question.

Comment: Agree, FF too is right on the need for a function name with a clear cut error message - SyntaxError: function statement requires a name

Comment: maybe because you can't do `function(){}()` (if not used as argument) but you can do `(function(){})()`

Comment: The first is undefined function syntax but the second is an object

Answer (score 28, accepted):

JavaScript has **function declarations** and **function expressions**. The former cannot be immediately invoked, while the latter can. It's a matter of the language grammar.

Function declaration:

```
function foo() {
    // ...
}
```

Function expression (on the right-hand side of the `=`):

```
var foo = function() {
    // ...
};
```

By adding parentheses around the function, you're forcing the function to be parsed as a function expression because it's not possible to put a function declaration within parentheses (where only expressions are expected and accepted):

```
(function foo() {
    // ...
});
```

You can then immediately invoke it:

```
(function foo() {
    // ...
})();
```

For a more detailed write-up, check out [Function Definitions in JavaScript](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/01/06/function-definitions-in-javascript).

Comment: Please notice that the canonical term is *function declaration*. "function statement" did mean something special pre-ES6.

Comment: @Bergi Of course, thanks. Corrected!

Answer (score 9):

The brackets in `(function(){})` mean that the function evaluates, the object is now contained inside the brackets, and this evaluation returns the function. It can be called, like this: `(function(){})();`.

`function(){}` does not evaluate. It makes sense for this to cause an error, because as you said, you will not be able to use it in any way.